# How do I merge two arrays in C#?

Tags: c#

Would it be possible to merge two arrays without using concat function or copy? I tried using copy but I'm looking for a method where it you don't need to use a function to merge two arrays. Thank you.

using System;

```
namespace console;
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()

        {
            try { 
        
                string input = "Enter the elements [{0}]: ";
                //User input for integer
                Console.Write("Please enter the first size of the array: ");
                int yourfirstArray = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
                int i;                                                    
                string[] yourArrays = new string[yourfirstArray]; 
                for (i = 0; i != yourArrays.Length; i++) 
                {
                    Console.Write(input, i, yourArrays[i]); 
                    yourArrays[i] = Console.ReadLine();     
                }

                Console.Write("Please enter the second size of the array: ");
                int yoursecondArray = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                 string[] myArrays = new string[yoursecondArray];
                 int j;
                for (j = 0; j != myArrays.Length; j++) 
                {
                    Console.Write(input, j, yourArrays[j]); 
                    yourArrays[j] = Console.ReadLine();     

                }
            
                string[] thisMerged = new string[myArrays.Length + yourArrays.Length];

                myArrays.CopyTo(thisMerged, 0);
                yourArrays.CopyTo(thisMerged, myArrays.Length);
                for (int k = 0; k != myArrays.Length; k++) 
                {
                    Console.Write("", i + myArrays[i], "", j + yourArrays[j]); 

                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("Please input the correct data value.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Using predefined functions providing the most time the best performance. Without Copy function you would end up using two for loops to copy it by yourself.